# phpbb center bbcode url

Tags: html, phpbb, phpbb3

I have a phpbb 3.1 forum, and im using the "center" bbcode, which changes

```
[center]{TEXT}[/center]
```

to

```
<center>{TEXT}</center>
```

If {TEXT} is some text like "this a centered text" the bbcode centers it.

if {TEXT} is some text and an url "this is a center text and www.google.es" the url can be clicked.

But if {TEXT} is only the url like "www.google.es" the url changes to plain text, and cannot be clickable...

how can I change the bbcode to make centered url clickable?

Comment: are you using `a` tags for the link? You probably have some styles you need to change. `a` tags on inline elements which can't be centered. You will have to think about using a `block` `inline-block` or `width 100% text-align center` type of deal.

Comment: I noticed that using any bbcode the url lost its hability to be clicked (i change the center tag to a div tag without align and the url changes to plain text too.

Answer (score 0):

phpBB has an internal function called `make_clickable` which automatically converts links into `<a>` tags in the posts.

Since your link is wrapped around with custom HTML through the BBCode, it does not attempt to make the link clickable.

You can work around this by using `[center][url]www.google.es[/url][/center]`